# delete duplicate strings in file in bash )with a catch)

Tags: bash, file, design-patterns, duplicates

This is my input file

```
apple
apples
appleby
roth
rothman
boss
cat
cater
caters
```

Expected output

```
apple
roth
boss
cat
cater
```

As you can see, i need to remove content that match pattern and keep the shortest match (as above). Have been breaking my head on this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: The task is not completely defined I guess. There are still too many possibilities to solve the task. E.g. if a file contains also just bare letters ... Can you define it more precisely?

Comment: Looks like this is some case of the LCS problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: What about the words `apple` and `crabapple`? Should `crabapple` be removed because of `apple`?

Comment: If possible, you should go for a more powerful language like `python`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sort the file, iterate over the words while maintaining a current prefix, if the current word does not start with the current prefix it's your new current prefix.

```
while read -r word; do
    if [ -z "$current_prefix" ] || [[ ! "$word" == "$current_prefix"* ]]; then
        current_prefix="$word"
        echo "$current_prefix"
    fi
done < <(sort input) > output
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/jorccp).

Comment: Thank you. it works perfectly. really appreciate your help.